# Preplace a field in MySQL with another field based on two columns

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm trying to set fields in a database in MySQL with another fields, based on two other fields.

This is just of one articleID in this table, however, it thould run on all:

Visualisation of the goal in mind
[image: Visualisation of the goal in mind]

My code is like this, but I'm afraid to test it out while it runs over a very big database without fast Backup possibilities. I've the feeling this is not yet right..

```
UPDATE table
SET pseudoprice = new_value
WHERE pricegroup = NL_NE
AND articleID = articleID IN (
SELECT pseudoprice = old_value
WHERE pricegroup = EK
AND articleID = articleID)
```

Ideas to move forward?

Comment: Ideas to move forward - test it on a small database..I cannot believe you are considering live testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to you sample seems you are looking for an update on the same table besed  on join

```
UPPDATE table t1
INNER JOIN table t2  ON t2.pricegroup  = 'EK'
    AND  t1 pricegroup= 'NL_NE'
SET t1.pseudoprice  = t2.pseudoprice
```

Comment: Yes this worked!

`UPDATE s_articles_prices dt1, s_articles_prices dt2 
SET dt1.pseudoprice = dt2.pseudoprice 
WHERE dt1.articleID = dt2.articleID 
AND dt1.pricegroup = 'NL_NE' 
AND dt2.pricegroup = 'EK' `